# Comparing a list of object with a list of int C#

Tags: c#

I´m trying to make a get method, which compares 2 list, one of int and one of a object. Det method should return all the objects or Ids, which isn't in the other list

```
 public List<ProductBO> GetAll()
    {
        using (var uow = facade.UnitOfWork)
        {
            return uow.ProductRepository.GetAll().Select(p => Pconv.Convert(p)).ToList();
        }
    }
    public List<ProductBO> GetFilteretProduct(List<int> ids)
    {


        var Product = GetAll();
        var FilteretProduct = Product.Where(p => !ids.Contains(p.IngredientIds));

        return FilteretProduct;

    }
```

When i test the code, it will return everything?

Comment: Isn't in is not the same as !=

Comment: != is not the same as Isn't in :)

Comment: Thanks. What can i use then :) ?

Comment: You wrote the code; if you want to know what it does, **run it**.

Comment: The code should return a list of object, which doesn't contain some specific ids

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method, although there might already be something in the framework that does this.`

```
public static class Extentions
{
    public static List<T> Filter<T>(this List<T> list, List<T> filterList)
    {
        return list.Where(v => !filterList.Contains(v)).ToList();
    }
}
```

and the use it:

```
var filteredList = list1.Filter(list2);
```

You might need to to change the details of the Contains statement to match your needs.

EDIT after great comment by @NetMage:

```
public static class Extentions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> NotIn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<T> filterList)
    {
        return list.Where(v => !filterList.Contains(v));
    }
}
```

Comment: Important to note that `Contains` is implementing `IEquatable`, which based on the type may now output desired result set.

Comment: Why are you doing `Select(r => r)`? Except when using `GroupBy` that accomplishes nothing useful.

Comment: I should have also mentioned I would make it accept and return `IEnumerable<T>` and leave off the `ToList()` - no reason to make it process early. And, of course, an `IQueryable` version as well. And possibly call it `NotIn` :)

Comment: Yep! I tried that but just couldn't get it to compile. It would be more clean and reusable that way, I agree.

Comment: And now of course, it works! :) Not sure what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your desired intent, would be:

```
var missing = example.Except(sample);
```

That will utilize the `IEquatable` which you can tweak for your own purposes.  [(About Except)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

You could also achieve this with the following:

```
var missing = example.Where(item => sample.Any(itm => item == itm));
```

This bit of code will return any item that isn't in your second collection.  With pretty basic Linq, granted the above isn't as performant as other approaches.  But you can accomplish this in an abundance of approaches.

Comment: Don't test against `true` or `false`.